Saving / Saved text in title bar
Whenever I save excel the title bar as text as Saving... - seems like at that time it syncs to the online changes.

If I try to close the file when this text is there, it doesn't gets close directly and we have popup as performing cleanup ( this doesn't goes off if we do not click cancel)
If I do not close and wait for few seconds, the text is changed to saved and then if I close it gets closed without any issues. That's good!


How to wait in VBA macro till the text gets changed to Saved from Saving... ? So that macro does save and cloose the excel with crashing it?
I do not want to have wait / sleep option here as the time it takes to change may differ on networks and the size of file.
I checked if this value is available in Document properties but was not able to locate as such.
Even WB.saved = True doesn't help.
Code:
Sub PushMaster()
Dim sWb As Workbook
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim mFile As String



mFile = "https://company.sharepoint.com/......../exception2024.xlsx" 'This file is having 12 tabs and file size is near 85mb

Set sWb = ThisWorkbook
Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(mFile)

sWb.Sheets(1).Range("A:A").Copy
Wb.Sheets("dec").Range("S:S").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

sWb.Sheets(1).Range("B:B").Copy
Wb.Sheets("dec").Range("T:T").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

sWb.Sheets(1).Range("C:C").Copy
Wb.Sheets("dec").Range("U:U").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues


Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Wb.Save
Wb.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

MsgBox "Done"
End Sub

It does wait till it get saved but only in local (cache?) and not while updates are being synced to SharePoint.
As the updates are not completed in SharePoint, and at the same time if macro executes WB.close I have a performance cleaning up box. And then this never goes away and need to hit cancel.


What are you actually trying to do? If you have code that saves the workbook, it can't progress until the workbook is saved.  Show the code you are using

It doesn't, I am using WB.save to save the file and then WB.close to close the file.

wb.Save does not allow the VBA to continue until the workbook is saved. You refer to online changes - is the workbook being saved directly to Sharepoint? Show the code you are using so we can understand your error handling and try to reproduce your problem.
Alternatively use the Workbook_BeforeSave and Workbook_AfterSave events to track whether or not a save is in progress

Yes workbook is directly opened from SharePoint and directly saved there as many users will be using the file and the changes should be live. I have also added the code into the question. @CHill60
